# when i refresh the page the form data automatically adding due to GET method when i remove it it show doesn't return httpresponse obj

Tags: python, django

> how can i use `is_valid()`  with `POST` method to get inputs from user
> my `views.py`  i also use `return redirect() and HttpResponseRedirect()` but it doesn't work

```
@login_required
def about(request):
    data= userdata.objects.all()
    form=student(request.POST) 
    if  request.method =='POST' or 'GET':
        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            email= request.POST.get('email')
            password =request.POST.get('password')
            fm = userdata(name=name,email=email,password=password)
            fm.save()
            form =student()
        else:
            form=student()
            

        return render(request,'about.html',{'form':form ,'data':data})
```

Comment: You're checking if it's a POST request after passing POST parameters to the form...

Comment: i remove the checking `POST `because i already  passing it , after  it also adding data while refreshing

Comment: Please check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/topics/forms/#the-view

Answer (score 1):

try the code below

```py
@login_required
def about(request):

    # i think you don't need 'data' and thus pass it in the context with 'form'
    # data= userdata.objects.all()

    if  request.method =='POST':  # POST request

        form=student(request.POST) 

        if form.is_valid():

            name = request.POST.get('name')
            email= request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            fm = userdata(name=name,email=email,password=password)
            fm.save()

            # Add flash message and then redirect 
            messages.success(request, 'SUCCESS !')
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('home'))

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the errors below.')
            #  if 'form.is_valid()' return false you will get all errors in 'form.errors' bag
            
    else:  # GET request
        form=student()

    return render(request,'about.html',{'form':form})
```

refer to :

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/topics/forms/#the-view
- https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipatterns/rendering_content_after_a_successful_post_request.html